# Undefined method `find_by_login' in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, messaging

I get the following error when I try to submit a form in my Rails 3 project. The form is used when 1 user sends a a message to another user, using the Simple Private Messaging plugin.

The way I have set the site up right now, users do not have to sign up or login in order to send a message.

**THE ERROR I AM GETTING**

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create

undefined method `find_by_login' for #<Class:0x12a374238>

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
def new
  @message = Message.new

  if params[:reply_to]
    @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
    unless @reply_to.nil?
      @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
      @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
      @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
    end
  end
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  @message.sender = @user
  @message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

  if @message.save
    flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
    redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

**MESSAGES>NEW VIEW (This is where Form is being created)**

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => messages_path(:user_id => @user) do |f| %>
<br>
<br />
<br />
<div class="field">
Hello! My name is <%= f.text_field :subject %> and I'm contacting you in response to your ad. I'm interested in learning more so get in touch! Here's my contact details: <%= f.text_field :body %>.
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn span6 large">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to

end
```

**USER MODEL**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts  
has_one :profile
has_private_messages

attr_accessible :email

validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message =>"Hmm, that email's already taken"
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^\s]+)((?:[-a-z0-9]\.)[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "Hi! Please use a valid email"

end
```

**USER MIGRATION**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.string :salt
  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

**RAILS CONSOLE OUTPUT ON FINDING USERS BY LOGIN**

```
>> u = User.first
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> nil
>> u.login
NoMethodError: undefined method `login' for nil:NilClass
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
from (irb):2
>>
```

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users do
 resources :messages
   end

resources :profiles
resources :pages
resources :posts

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

Comment: is `login` a table of your User model?

Comment: @apneadiving no, it is not. see user migration added above. do i need to add it? if so what's the fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_by_attribute` (`find_by_login` in your case) is a dynamic method added by Rails if you have a column called `login` in your DB table (The `users` table in your case). Since you're `users` table doesn't contain a `login` column your `User` model haven't a `login` attribute and haven't a `find_by_login` method.

Since you have an `email` column try to replace the offending line with this

```
@message.recipient = User.find_by_email(params[:message][:to])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try in console:

```
u = User.first
u.login
```

What do you get? It looks like you don't have a login attribute in your user model, you have an email attribute. So, you need to use `find_by_email` instead.

Comment: see console output attached above. if i try switching to 'find_by_email' i get an "undefined method `user_messages_path'" error in the messages controller..

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call `user_messages_path(@user)` without defining `@user`. Also if you have no users in your DB (as your console example shows) then any find will return nil, meaning you must catch nils in the rest of your code. It's good to catch nils anyway in case you later add conditions that might result in 0 results.

Comment: Actually -- `undefined method user_messages_path` means your routes are not setup correctly. Your routes must include at least `resources :users do   resources :messages   end` in order to have a `user_messages_path` method.

Comment: I updated the config/routes.rb file as you said, but now get a no routes match message for "/messages/new". "/messages/new" is the path I use to bring up the message form..what should I do?

Comment: thanks for your detailed feedback..going to put the remaining bugs in a new post to make things simpler to follow..